# Defining a linear map to agree with other linear maps on subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm trying to prove the following property about linear maps as I can use it in larger proof I am working on. Although, I am not fully convinced of it.

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space and $W, W'$ subspaces. Given two linear maps $p,q : V \to U$ that agree on $W \cap W'$. There there exists a linear map $r : V \to U$ such that $r$ agrees with $p$ on $W$ and $r$ agrees with $q$ on $W'$.

I'm not sure if this will make a difference, but I am also working with finite fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is true. Take a basis $B_{W \cap W'} = \{e_1, ..., e_k\}$ for $W \cap W'$, then extend it to bases $B_W = \{e_1, ..., e_k, w_1, ..., w_\ell\}$ and $B_{W'} = \{e_1, ..., e_k, w_1', ..., w_m'\}$ for $W$ and $W'$ respectively. I claim that $B_{W+W'} = B_W \cup B_{W'}$ is a linearly independent set, otherwise $W \cap W'$ would have been larger. (See if you can prove that more formally.) Then you can extend that to a basis of the full space $V$.

With this basis, you can define your function $r$ by choosing its values on the basis vectors, and you can set those to be equal to $p$ and $q$ on the bases $B_W$ and $B_{W'}$ respectively.